# Xenon Light Turns off

Tags: troubleshooting

Xenon Light on passenger side of my MB SLK 230 turn off after few minutes, if you turn the headlights switch off and on again, they stay on again for a few more minutes and go off again.  What's the problem?

Comment: A broken Xenon Burner or, worst case, controller?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest @Daniel is probably correct.